Fill boxes with text in React then continue to the next box
Here's a photo of what I have in mind:

I have a simple card component like so:
function Card({ width, height, text }) {
  return (
    <div className="card" style={{ width, height }}>
      {text}
    </div>
  );
}

Each card has an arbitrary width and height. There is a very long text to be spread out across several cards. The next card should pick up the rest of the string that did not fit in the previous card.
It is important that the card must not be scrollable and the card's size must not expand.
I created a Codepen here to demonstrate, but the filled text is hardcoded. Ideally of course I'd supply one very long string and there's a way to spread out that string across several cards.
https://codepen.io/skeithtan/pen/gOVrMLR
How do I go about doing this?

What is your problem sorry ? I didn't understand ?

I have a card component that displays text, with each card having a fixed size. I want to take a long piece of text and automatically spread it across multiple cards without any resizing, or scrolling. I’m looking for help on how to make this work.

This is not a problem, you are seeking for someone to do your code. Try something, and if you face any problem, we will help.

Are you now the authority on what goes in Stackoverflow and what doesn't?

I am not, but they are rules. I will firstly tell you to use ChatGPT, then to forget to use a specific height for your cards, to hard to calculate, just use align-items: flex-start on your container.

If you think this post violates the site rules, please feel free to flag the post. Otherwise, no, I cannot forget a specific part of the problem, the fixed height is important. Flexboxes does not solve spreading out the string in several containers.

Thanks for the codepen. It can't be like this because the cards must have a fixed width and height. If you attempt to change the height in the solution, it no longer fills the card with words. It must be possible to change the width and height of any card and still fill it correctly.

I created <BoxedText/> component and i used splitTextIntoChunks() function to split text into chunks that fit within a dynamic box size.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const BoxedText = ({ text, boxSizes }) => {
  const [textChunks, setTextChunks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to split text into chunks that fit within a dynamic box size
    const splitTextIntoChunks = (text, boxSizes) => {
      const words = text.split(' ');
      const chunks = [];
      let currentChunk = '';
      let boxIndex = 0;

      let tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
      tempDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
      tempDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      tempDiv.style.fontSize = '16px';
      document.body.appendChild(tempDiv);

      words.forEach((word) => {
        // Set the current box size dynamically
        const { width, height } = boxSizes[boxIndex];
        tempDiv.style.width = `${width}px`;

        tempDiv.innerHTML = currentChunk + (currentChunk ? ' ' : '') + word;

        // If the content overflows, save the chunk and move to the next box
        if (tempDiv.offsetHeight > height) {
          chunks.push({ chunk: currentChunk, width, height });
          currentChunk = word;
          boxIndex = (boxIndex + 1) % boxSizes.length; // Move to next box
        } else {
          currentChunk += (currentChunk ? ' ' : '') + word;
        }
      });

      if (currentChunk) {
        const { width, height } = boxSizes[boxIndex];
        chunks.push({ chunk: currentChunk, width, height });
      }

      document.body.removeChild(tempDiv);
      return chunks;
    };

    // Split the text based on the box sizes when the component mounts
    const chunks = splitTextIntoChunks(text, boxSizes);
    setTextChunks(chunks);
  }, [text, boxSizes]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
      {textChunks.map((chunkData, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            width: `${chunkData.width}px`,
            height: `${chunkData.height}px`,
            border: '1px solid black',
            margin: '5px',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            padding: '10px',
          }}
        >
          {chunkData.chunk}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default BoxedText;

And passed text and sizes of all boxes in props.
import BoxedText from "./BoxedText";

export default function App() {
  const text = `Once upon a time...`;
  
  // Define different sizes for each box
  const boxSizes = [
    { width: 200, height: 200 },
    { width: 160, height: 400 },
    { width: 300, height: 270 },
    { width: 200, height: 230 },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <BoxedText text={text} boxSizes={boxSizes} />
    </div>
  );
}


This is helpful, thank you
